# Get elements from list of lists

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

is it possible to get all elements from list of lists in Prolog?

Something like: We have getElements([[[a,b,[c]],d,e],f,g,[h,[i,j]]],S) and the result is: S = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j] ...

Thanks for help.

Comment: research bar + "flatten" should make you happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog (and maybe others), you can use `flatten/2`:

```
?- flatten([[[a,b,[c]],d,e],f,g,[h,[i,j]]], S).
S = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i|...].
```

Note that [the SWI-Prolog manual page for `flatten/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2) includes the following statement:

> Ending up needing flatten/3 often indicates, like append/3 for appending two lists, a bad design.

However, the page doesn't say whether there is another native predicate to replace it.

I'm sure a better answer will be supplied.

Comment: ok thanks :) didnt know it... although I hoped little bit that I'll find out the trick - some algorithm... but thanks ;) (and sorry for my english O:-))

Comment: You can see the source/how it is implemented here.. http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/lists.pl?show=src

Comment: @magus: This predicate is deprecated. Please read it justification in the source you mention: Ending up needing flatten/3 often indicates,
like append/3 for appending two lists, a bad
design.  Efficient code that generates lists
from generated small lists must use difference
lists, often possible through grammar rules for
optimal readability.

Answer (score 5):

You asked for all elements of a list of lists.  That is, for `[[1,2,3],[4]]`  this would be the list `[1,2,3,4]`. However, for `[[[1],[3]]]` this would be the list `[[1],[3]]` since `[1]` and `[3]` are elements. For this reason, `flatten/2` is incorrect it gives you `[1,3]` as an answer. Also, for `1` it gives `[1]`...

Here is a solution using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg):

```
seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

seqq([]) --> [].
seqq([Es|Ess]) --> seq(Es), seqq(Ess).

?- phrase(seqq([[[1],[3]]]), Xs).
   Xs = [[1],[3]].
?- phrase(seqq(1), Xs).
   false.
```

This solution now works also for cases like the following:

```
?- phrase(seqq([S1,S2]), [1,2]).
   S1 = [], S2 = [1,2]
;  S1 = [1], S2 = [2]
;  S1 = [1,2], S2 = []
;  false.
```

Whereas `flatten/2` is completely wrong:

```
?- flatten([S1,S2],[1,2]).
   S1 = 1, S2 = 2.
```