# prolog access part of output form predicate

Tags: prolog

i am trying to write a prolog program that recommends hobbies based on a persons likes. the program also contains a language parser that finds any verbs or nouns in a sentence.

i am wondering if i can access certain parts of the output of my language parser. the output of my parser looks like `R = sentence(np(np(det(an), np2(adj(old), np2(noun(father))))), vp(vp(verb(likes), np(det(a), np2(adj(good), np2(noun(book)))))))` i want to see the value of the verb (likes) and the second noun (book).

```
input(Input sentence):-
    sentence(Input sentence,Output of parser),
    recommend(Output of parser(verb), Output of parser(noun), recommendation).
```

my code would sort of look like above but with `Out(verb)` and `Out(noun)` being proper prolog syntax

how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Look at univ operator in prolog `=..`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000090/flatten-term-prolog The answer to this question is what you are looking for.

Comment: Looks like someone asked the same thing on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/aft88d/access_part_of_output_form_predicate/