# Predicates with =.. operator in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Last time I learnt about =.. that can translate a list to term and opposite.
I have 3 predicates to do, first one is the one that translates a list to a term. I came up with sth like this:

```
list_to_term(List, Functor, Term) :-
    Term =.. [Functor | List].
```

Is it okey? Enough? Or I miss something?

The other predicate is `count(A,T,N)` for element A, in term T with number N that is true if N is a count of elements A in term T... Can anyone help me with this one or how to start?

```
 ?- count(a,f(a),N).
 N = 1
 ?- count(a,f(a,g(b,a),N).
 N = 2.
 ?- count(a,f(a,g(X,a),N).
 N = 2.
```

Comment: There is something broken with your terms in the second and third example.

Comment: which one's boken? list_to_term - i am not sure if I did it correctly... The other one is just an exercise to be done

Comment: the call `count(a,f(a,g(b,a),N).` has no "balancing" brackets.

Comment: it's copied from exercise... But probably it should be  count(a,f(a,g(X,a)),N).

Comment: Hint: recursively "unpack" the functor, and keep track of the number of times an argument matches.

Comment: In addition to Willem's comments, when you implement `count` (which, by the way, should be called something more specific, like, `count_argument`, for clarity) use `==/2` rather than `=/2` to check for an argument match.

Comment: @Willem so sth like: count(A,T,N) :- T =.. [F|L], count(A,F,N1), count(A,L,N2), N is N1+N2 ?

Comment: @heisenberg7584: perhaps it is better to first construct a predicate that can enumerate all arguments (and sub arguments recursively).

Comment: @heisenberg7584 your suggestion for a recursive solution isn't quite right since you're mixing kinds of terms in one of the arguments.`count` accepts a compound term as its second argument, but `count(A, L, N2)` uses a *list of terms* in `L`, so this won't work (unless you write `count` to handle that case as well).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000090/flatten-term-prolog) you can reuse the predicate `flatten_term/2`, a little bit modified to handle free variables, to sove your problem. Here is the code for a basic solution:

```
flatten_term(Term,[Term]):-
    (atomic(Term);var(Term)),!.
flatten_term(Term,Flat):-
    Term =.. TermList,
    flatten_term_list(TermList,Flat),!.

flatten_term_list([],[]):-!.
flatten_term_list([H|T],List):-
    flatten_term(H,HList),
    flatten_term_list(T,TList),
    append(HList,TList,List),!.

occurrences(_,[],N,N):-!.
occurrences(A,[H|T],N,Tot):-
    A \== H,!,
    occurrences(A,T,N,Tot).
occurrences(A,[H|T],N,Tot):-
    A == H,!,
    N1 is N+1,
    occurrences(A,T,N1,Tot).

count(A,Term,N):-
    flatten_term(Term,Flatten),
    occurrences(A,Flatten,0,N).

?- count(a,f(a,g(X,a),d),T).
T = 2.

?- count(X,f(a,g(X,a),d),T).
T = 1
```

First of all you flatten the term using `flatten_term/2`. Then simply count the occurrences of the element you want to find using `occurrences/4`. You can, if you want, modify `flatten_term/2` to avoid the usage of `occurrences/4` and so scan the term (list) only one time... Something like: `flatten_term(Term,Flatten,ElementToFind,Counter,Total)`.

Comment: thanks! @damianodamiano, looks like a pretty decent solution but really long and complicated, comparing to exercises I have I think that it must be a bit simpler to be done... But still thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Start by solving a more general problem of counting the terms *in a list*. Processing a term is processing a singleton list containing that term, after all:

```erlang
count(A,T,N):- count(A, [T|Z],Z, 0,N).

count(_, [],  [], C,N):- N is C, !.
count(A, [T|B],Z, C,N):- ?=(A,T), A=T, !, count(A, B,Z, C+1,N).
count(A, [T|B],Z, C,N):- ?=(A,T), T=..[_|S], !, append(S,Y,Z), count(A, B,Y, C,N).
count(A, [_|B],Z, C,N):- count(A, B,Z, C,N).
```

This opens up each head term in a *list* in succession and appends its argument terms to that *list* thus using it as a *queue*... thus processing the predicate's second argument `T` in a *breadth-first* manner.

This assumes `A` argument is an atom, and `?=` is used to avoid instantiating the free variables we might encounter, and instead to skip over them, as your examples seem to indicate.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it okey? Enough? Or I miss something?

Prolog's [**`=../2`** predicate [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) can "pack" and "unpack" a list that contains the functor name and its arguments in a term and vice versa. So one can use this to *construct* a term, or to *analyze* a term. For example:

```
?- f(a,g(b,a)) =.. L.
L = [f, a, g(b, a)].
```

Here `f` is the functor name, and `a` and `g(b, a)` are the arguments. These arguments can be terms as well, and then we thus need to unpack these arguments further.

We can for example obtain all the subterms of a term with:

```
subterms(T, T) :-
    \+ var(T).
subterms(T, ST) :-
    \+ var(T),
    T =.. [_|As],
    member(A, As),
    subterms(A, ST).
```

For example:

```
?- subterms(f(a,g(X,a)),N).
N = f(a, g(X, a)) ;
N = a ;
N = g(X, a) ;
N = a ;
false.
```

Now that we obtained all (sub)terms, we can slightly rewrite the predicate to *count* the number of elements that match:

```
subterm_query(Q, T) :-
    Q == T.
subterm_query(Q, T) :-
    \+ var(T),
    T =.. [_|As],
    member(A, As),
    subterm_query(Q, A).
```

so we obtain if we query for `a`:

```
?- subterm_query(a, f(a,g(X,a))).
true ;
true ;
false.
```

If we can use the [**`aggregate`** library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate), we can make use of the [**`aggregate_all/3`** predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=aggregate_all/3) to count the number of times, the predicate was succesful:

```
?- aggregate_all(count, subterm_query(a, f(a,g(X,a))), Count).
Count = 2.
```

If not, you need to implement a mechanism that returns `1` for a match, and sums up recursively the matches of the child terms. I leave this as an exercise.