# Flattening only one level of a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, flatten

I'm working on a problem to flatten only one level of a list in Prolog.  For example, `[[1],[2,3]]` would become `[1,2,3]`, but `[[1,[2]],3]` would only flatten down to `[1,[2],3]`.  I went through some other questions on the site, but none thoroughly answered this question, and I just can't get my code to work on all my test cases.

---

**Update**: the code works!  Here is the eventual **answer** that I came to:

```
my_flatten([], []).
my_flatten([A|B],L) :- is_list(A), my_flatten(B,B1), !, append(A,B1,L).
my_flatten([A|B],[A|B1]) :- my_flatten(B,B1).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get elements from list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777077/get-elements-from-list-of-lists)

Comment: The best is to [use DCGs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9787502/772868).

Comment: What do you mean by "works only about half the time?"

Comment: I mean that the test cases I presented don't work, but others do.  For some--like the ones I showed in my post, it simply outputs the empty list.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the example with "output" `[]`

Comment: Also, state test cases such that they are easy to copy-paste: e.g. `flat([1,[2,3]], R)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 simple clauses, I will show just the most complex one

```
flat([H|T],R) :- is_list(H), flat(T,T1), append(H,T1,R).
```

other two clauses are the base recursion case, and a `copy as is` of head to result.

You should also place a cut in the clause I've shown, otherwise on backtracking you'll get wrong results (due to firing of the clause `copy as is`)

Comment: So `flat([A,B], [1,2])` fails?

Comment: that is just as bad. Both A and B have to be lists.

Comment: @false: why ? flat([1,2],[1,2]) it's fine, I think

Comment: At least we can agree that `flat([[1,2],[]],[1,2])` is true. Therefore also `flat([A,B],[1,2]), A = [1,2], B = []` should succeed.

Comment: @CapelliC I've played with my code a bit and so far, gotten to

`flat([], []). 
flat([H|T],R) :- is_list(H), flat(T,T1), !, append(H,T1,R).
 flat(H,H).`

which is actually the best-working code I've gotten so far.  It works in all cases I've tried except for when I input [1,[2,3]], when it just returns the same thing.  Also, I believe I am allowed to assume that the input will always be a list--does that affect this?  I'm sorry I'm such a noob at Prolog...

Comment: Nevermind, my last clause was messing it up, I got it!  Thank you, your answer was very helpful!!  I will update my original question with what I came to that works :)

Answer (score 0):

This are the results obtained with the predicate described at the bottom. With *flat_lvl* predicate u can specify the desired level for flat a list.

Examples:

```
% Lis= [[e1, e2, [e31, e32]], [e4, e5, e6, e7], [e8, e9]],
% flat_lvl(Lis, FlatLis, 2).
%
% ---> FlatLis = [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9]


% Lis= [[e1, e2, [e31, e32]], [e4, e5, e6, e7], [e8, e9]],
% flat_lvl(Lis, FlatLis, 1).
%
% ---> FlatLis = [e1, e2, [e31, e32], e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9]


% Lis= [[e1, e2, [e31, e32]], [e4, e5, e6, e7], [e8, e9]],
% flat_lvl(Lis, FlatLis, 0).
%
% ---> FlatLis = [[e1, e2, [e31, e32]], [e4, e5, e6, e7], [e8, e9]]
```

The predicate to flat a list with a specified level is the following, so just set DeepLvl to 1:

```
flat_lvl([],[],_).
flat_lvl([LisH| LisT], FlatLis, DeepLvl):-
    Lvl is DeepLvl - 1, Lvl >= -1,
    (flat_lvl(LisH, FlatH, Lvl); FlatH= [LisH]),
    flat_lvl(LisT, FlatTail, DeepLvl),
    append(FlatH, FlatTail, FlatLis), !.

?- flat_lvl(List, 1).
```