# Define predicate in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm struggling with this one:

> Define predicate `len_NM(L,N,M)` which checks if a certain list of lists `L` contains at least `N` elements with length no less than `M`.

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Comment: What is your question? Do you want us to write code for you? It is easy, but it is not working like this.

Comment: so easy, indeed: len_NM(L,N,M) :- aggregate(count,(member(E,L),length(E,T),T>=M),C), C >= N.

Answer (score 1):

1. The OP stated:

   > Define predicate `len_NM(L,N,M)` which checks if a certain list of lists `L` contains **at least** `N` elements with length no less than `M`.
2. In this answer we do not solve the original problem, but the following variation:

   > Define predicate `len_NM(L,N,M)` which checks if a certain list of lists `L` contains **exactly** `N` elements with length no less than `M`.
3. Similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9787502/4609915), we define [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)  `seqq1//1` to establish the relationship between a list of non-empty lists and its flattened opposite:

   ```
   seq([])     --> [].
   seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

   seqq1([])       --> [].
   seqq1([Es|Ess]) --> {Es=[_|_]}, seq(Es), seqq1(Ess).
   ```

   Sample use:

   ```
   ?- phrase(seqq1([[1,2],[3],[4]]),Xs).
   Xs = [1,2,3,4].
   ```

   Note that `seqq1//1` works in "both directions":

   ```
   ?- phrase(seqq1(Xss),[1,2,3,4]).
     Xss = [[1],[2],[3],[4]] 
   ; Xss = [[1],[2],[3,4]]
   ; Xss = [[1],[2,3],[4]]
   ; Xss = [[1],[2,3,4]]
   ; Xss = [[1,2],[3],[4]]
   ; Xss = [[1,2],[3,4]]
   ; Xss = [[1,2,3],[4]]
   ; Xss = [[1,2,3,4]]
   ; false.
   ```
4. In this answer we use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

   ```
   :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
   ```

   Then, we define `len_NM/4`—using [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915),
   [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue), [`tcount/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/4609915), and [`(#=<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915):

   ```
   len_NM(Xss,Ys,N,M) :-
      M #>= 1,
      N #>= 0,
      phrase(seqq1(Xss),Ys),
      maplist(length,Xss,Ls),
      tcount(#=<(M),Ls,N).
   ```

---

Let's run some sample queries!

```
?- len_NM([[1,2,3],[4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12]],_,N,L).
  N = 5, L = 1             % five lists have length of at least one 
; N = 4, L = 2             % four lists have length of at least two
; N = 2, L = 3             % two of at least three (e.g., [1,2,3] and [7,8,9,10])
; N = 1, L = 4             % one list has length of four (or more)
; N = 0, L in 5..sup.      % no list has length of five (or more)
```

OK! How about this one?

```
?- append(Xs,_,[x,x,x,x,x,x]),   % With `Xs` having at most 6 elements ...
   N #>= 1,                      % ... `Xss` shall contain at least 1 list ...
   len_NM(Xss,Xs,N,4).           % ... having a length of 4 (or more).
  Xs = [x,x,x,x],     N = 1, Xss = [[x,x,x,x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x],   N = 1, Xss = [[x],[x,x,x,x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x],   N = 1, Xss = [[x,x,x,x],[x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x],   N = 1, Xss = [[x,x,x,x,x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x,x], N = 1, Xss = [[x],[x],[x,x,x,x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x,x], N = 1, Xss = [[x],[x,x,x,x],[x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x,x], N = 1, Xss = [[x],[x,x,x,x,x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x,x], N = 1, Xss = [[x,x],[x,x,x,x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x,x], N = 1, Xss = [[x,x,x,x],[x],[x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x,x], N = 1, Xss = [[x,x,x,x],[x,x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x,x], N = 1, Xss = [[x,x,x,x,x],[x]]
; Xs = [x,x,x,x,x,x], N = 1, Xss = [[x,x,x,x,x,x]]
; false.
```