# Prolog: searching for sublists of length>=3

Tags: list, prolog

I'd like to produce a predicate which is able to check whether a list will divide into sublists each containing at least three atoms.

For example:

```
findgroups([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],L1).
```

Has solutions such as:

```
L1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
L1=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
L1=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
L1=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

However, the following will fail:

```
findgroups([1,2,3,4,5]).
```

I have written a few predicates based on splitting lists into two sub terms using append, but I'm confused about handling multiple sublists.

Thank you very much for your help

With Best wishes
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this very simple solution could do

```
findgroups([], []).
findgroups(L, [[A,B,C|D]|Gs]) :-
    append([A,B,C|D], R, L),
    findgroups(R, Gs).
```

The last one solution is not requested, but it's correct, since you don't rule out a group of only 1 element

```
?- findgroups([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], Gs).
Gs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] ;
Gs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] ;
Gs = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] ;
Gs = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]] ;
Gs = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] ;
Gs = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8|...]] ;
false.
```

To match exactly the examples, I would write

```
findgroups(L, Gs) :- findgroups_(L, Gs), Gs = [_,_|_].
findgroups_([], []).
findgroups_(L, [[A,B,C|D]|Gs]) :-
    append([A,B,C|D], R, L),
    findgroups_(R, Gs).
```

Comment: Thanks both for your excellent responses, which helped me learn a lot. I am currently experimenting with adding additional goals to constrain the grouping further.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with a good name! `findgroups/2` that means you want to command Prolog: Prolog do find me some groups! And hurry up! Is this really fit? Let's see:

```
?- findgroups(L, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).
```

Who is finding here any group? They are already present! So your name is really a misnomer. Instead, compose a name by describing each argument. The first argument is about a list, the second about a list of lists. So:

```
?- list_lists(L, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).
```

Better, but a bit too general. Maybe:

```
?- elements_trigroups(L, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).
```

So the query now reads: Here are all the trigroups, what are the corresponding elements? Elements is such a lengthy word, els is just as nice.

My first (and a little bit too general) attempt:

```
es_trigroups(Es, Ess) :-
   phrase(seqq(Ess), Es).
```

Note the variable names: `Es`: a list of `E`s. And `Ess` is a list of `Es`s which in turn is a list of `E`s.

Using `seqq//1` defined in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9787502/772868).

Darn, it still succeeds for:

```
?- es_trigroups([1,2,3,4,5], [Es,Fs]).
   Es = [], Fs = [1,2,3,4,5]
;  Es = [1], Fs = [2,3,4,5]
;  ... .
```

But it is not that bad, for it succeeds for all the cases you demanded. Brief: The relation is too general. We need to specialize it.

A simple way to specialize a relation is to add further goals like:

```
es_trigroups(Es, Ess) :-
   trigroups(Ess),
   phrase(seqq(Ess), Es).

trigroups([]).
trigroups([Es|Ess]) :-
   Es = [_,_,_|_],
   trigroups(Ess).
```

So now everything seems fine. There is only one thing, that is not that nice: The [termination property](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cti/cgi/cti?texta=seq%28%5B%5D%29+--%3E+%5B%5D.%0D%0Aseq%28%5BE%7CEs%5D%29+--%3E+%5BE%5D%2C+seq%28Es%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Aseqq%28%5B%5D%29+--%3E+%5B%5D.%0D%0Aseqq%28%5BEs%7CEss%5D%29+--%3E+seq%28Es%29%2C+seqq%28Ess%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Aes_trigroups%28Es%2C+Ess%29+%3A-%0D%0A+++trigroups%28Ess%29%2C%0D%0A+++phrase%28seqq%28Ess%29%2C+Es%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Aes_trigroups_bis%28Es%2C+Ess%29+%3A-%0D%0A+++phrase%28seqq%28Ess%29%2C+Es%29%2C%0D%0A+++trigroups%28Ess%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Atrigroups%28%5B%5D%29.%0D%0Atrigroups%28%5BEs%7CEss%5D%29+%3A-%0D%0A+++Es+%3D+%5B_%2C_%2C_%7C_%5D%2C%0D%0A+++trigroups%28Ess%29.) could be better. Sometimes we will need to exchange the goals.

```
es_trigroups_bis(Es, Ess) :-
   phrase(seqq(Ess), Es),
   trigroups(Ess).
```

The resulting termination conditions read:

```
es_trigroups(A,B)terminates_if b(B).
    % optimal. loops found: [es_trigroups(_,[[_,_,_|_]|_]),es_trigroups(y,[[_,_,_|_]|_])]. NTI took    0ms,74i,74i
es_trigroups_bis(A,B)terminates_if b(B).
    % optimal. loops found: [es_trigroups_bis(_,[[]|_]),es_trigroups_bis(y,[[]|_])]. NTI took    0ms,79i,79i
```

But what we actually want, is that the termination condition not only depends on `B` (the second argument), but also on `A` alone. That is that either `A` or `B` alone can guarantee termination. To this end, we have to interlace both definitions:

```
es_trigroups_ter(Es, Ess) :-
   phrase(seq3s(Ess), Es).

seq3s([]) --> [].
seq3s([Es|Ess]) --> {Es = [_,_,_|_]}, seq(Es), seq3s(Ess).
```

Now, termination conditions are [excellent](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cti/cgi/cti?texta=es_trigroups_ter%28Es%2C+Ess%29+%3A-%0D%0A+++phrase%28seq3s%28Ess%29%2C+Es%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Aseq%28%5B%5D%29+--%3E+%5B%5D.%0D%0Aseq%28%5BE%7CEs%5D%29+--%3E+%5BE%5D%2C+seq%28Es%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Aseq3s%28%5B%5D%29+--%3E+%5B%5D.%0D%0Aseq3s%28%5BEs%7CEss%5D%29+--%3E+%7BEs+%3D+%5B_%2C_%2C_%7C_%5D%7D%2C+seq%28Es%29%2C+seq3s%28Ess%29.)!

```
es_trigroups_ter(A,B)terminates_if b(A);b(B).
    % optimal. loops found: [es_trigroups_ter([A|_],[[A,_,_|_]|_])]. NTI took    0ms,77i,77i
```