# I am having problems getting a list of lists into a single list

Tags: prolog

I am writing a solution to working out distances between numbers in a list using recursion, but have been struggling with getting the intended output.
I am trying to get a list of lists into a single list, but attempts at using flatten and append/2 aren't working. I have tried for hours, and keep going around in circles, can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

difference([],_,[]).
differwnce([L|Ls],X,[DST|Ds]) :-
   DST #= abs(X - L),
   difference(Ls,X,Ds).

differences[],[]).
differences([L|Ls], [DST|Tail]) :-
   difference(Ls,X,DST),
   differences(Ls, Tail).
```

Here is the intended input and output:-

```
?- differences([1,2,4,9],Ds).
Ds = [1,3,8,2,7,5].
```

Current Output:

```
Ds = [[1,3,8],[2,7],[5],[]].
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question so we can see what you've tried

Comment: Sorry, i'm a newbie to posting question on Stackoverflow and got a bit confused with the formatting. It should be up now. Thanks.

Comment: Rolled back code you deleted because it is specific to the question. Your code used constraints in the example and thus made the answers more specific. By deleting the code beginners reading this might think that constraints are required and they are not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get elements from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777077/get-elements-from-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `distances/3` predicate into a `distances/4` predicate that returns a list tail for the elements that will follow, effectively using an *open list*:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

distances([], _, Tail, Tail).
distances([BN| Bs], B, [DST| Ds], Tail) :-
   DST #= abs(B - BN),
   distances(Bs, B, Ds, Tail).

triangle([], []).
triangle([BN| Bs], Ds) :-
    distances(Bs, BN, Ds, Tail),
    triangle(Bs, Tail).
```

Sample call:

```
?- triangle([1,2,4,9], Ds).
Ds = [1, 3, 8, 2, 7, 5].
```

To better understand this solution consider the results of the following query:

```
?- distances([2,4,9], 1, Ds, Tail).
Ds = [1, 3, 8| Tail].
```

This solution is more efficient than calling predicates such as `append/2` or `flatten/3` at the end.

P.S. If you still need a `distances/3` predicate to use elsewhere, you can define it easily:

```
distances(Bs, B, Ds) :-
    distances(Bs, B, Ds, []).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paulo I will try this. My only issue is that I am restricted to have a distances/3 predicate. I could however set up another too using what you have suggested? Or is there another way I can keep distances/3?

Comment: @AntMan You can define `distances/3` using `distances/4` easily: `distances(Bs,B,Ds) :- distances(Bs,B,Ds,[]).`. Will that work in your case?

Comment: Perfect Paulo, thanks! This has had me stuck for so many hours. I was trying to use append(ds, DST) for ages after the triangle recursive call, but it just wouldn't put it into a separate list. Do you know why that is? It's illogical lol, since append/2 is supposed to take a list of lists and concatenate into one list

Comment: @AntMan Note that my answer is more efficient than any solution calling append or flatten predicates.

Comment: It's great. I was also trying different ways to make another List and manually put the elements in for hours yesterday, and it was just not working. Trying to understand how it works still though.. The extra Tail is taking whatever is left over from the call to distances? I'm a little confused, but great that it works

Answer (score 2):

```
seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

seqq([]) --> [].
seqq([Es|Ess]) -->
  seq(Es),
  seqq(Ess).

?- phrase(seqq([[1,3,8],[2,7],[5],[]]), Es).
   Es = [1,3,8,2,7,5].
?- dif(A,B), phrase(seqq([[A|_]|_]), [B|_]).
   false.
```

Comment: Sorry this has confused me more. I am very much a beginner to swi prolog, is there a simpler solution please?

Comment: Hi false, do you mean set up another predicate to manually convert the list? Like append/2 usually does? Can you tell me why append/2 doesn't work in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the library predicate [`append/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) like so?

```
?- append([[1,3,8],[2,7],[5],[]], Xs).
Xs = [1,3,8,2,7,5].
```

Comment: @repeat i couldnt get it to work with my code, i dont know why. That was my original question

Comment: It didnt like using Ds in append, even though its a list of lists i assume

Comment: Use `append/2`: once at the end as a quick fix, not in the recursive clause.

Comment: It needs to be within the recursive predicate or at least call another predicate from the recursive predicate to append. I couldnt get it to work this way either though. I think i need to learn more about prolog fundamentals to understand why

Comment: *Why not use the library predicate append/2 like so?* because append/2 produces many unnecessary errors like in `dif(A,B), append([[A|_]|_], [B|_]).` which could fail silently